# EMR hadoop error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

What may be the cause of this error. When I tried in my local machine it works but when I try to deploy it in AWS EMR I get this error. Thanks

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArticleLess$Reduce
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getCombinerClass(JobConf.java:1028)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombinerRunner.create(Task.java:1380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:997)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArticleLess$Reduce
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:867)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:891)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ArticleLess$Reduce
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:865)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop ClassNotFoundException related to MapClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339356/hadoop-classnotfoundexception-related-to-mapclass)

Comment: Judging by the answer in a very similar question, I'd say you probably just need to put your class into a package.

Answer (score 0):

During compile/run on your local maschine, you used the class "ArticleLess",  which is not present on EMR

I searched on google, but I did not find this class. So, I assume it is a class from your code (not an open source lib).

Search for the class in your code. If you use *.jar files, copy & rename them to *.zip, search inside.

When you have found the class, you must deploy the class / the whole jar to EMR. How you do this depends on how you are starting job (which you did not describe).